# Refer to a field (Model.field) with a variable (@field)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a variable called `@field` that is set to equal a field name, like `@field = "city"`.

How can I use that variable to access `Model.city`? Literally, how can I get `Model.@field` to work?

Comment: Using send. Model.send( @field )

Comment: Thanks Syed! If you put that into an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using send. Model.send( @field )